# WordWrap не работает

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout, qlabel, wordwrap

Помогите наладить работу WordWrap.

**main.py**

```
...
from descriptionperson_ui import Ui_descriptionperson

class DescriptionPersonPreview(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_descriptionperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
        self.ui.scroll.setPixmap(QPixmap())
        self.textaboutpreview = text
        self.ui.textabout.setText(self.textaboutpreview)
        self.ui.textabout.setWordWrap(True)
        self.ui.scroll.setPixmap(QPixmap("images/scroll.png"))
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)

...
```

**descriptionperson_ui.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_descriptionperson(object):
    def setupUi(self, descriptionperson):
        descriptionperson.setObjectName("descriptionperson")
        descriptionperson.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        descriptionperson.resize(800, 850)
        self.warning = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.warning.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 61, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Moscow Sans Regular")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.warning.setFont(font)
        self.warning.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.warning.setObjectName("warning")
        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.scroll.setEnabled(True)
        self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 850))
        self.scroll.setText("")
        self.scroll.setObjectName("scroll")
        self.textabout = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.textabout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 110, 581, 541))
        self.textabout.setText("")
        self.textabout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.textabout.setObjectName("textabout")
        self.inputname = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.inputname.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(173, 653, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.inputname.setFont(font)
        self.inputname.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.inputname.setObjectName("inputname")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(descriptionperson)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(353, 674, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.check = QtWidgets.QPushButton(descriptionperson)
        self.check.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(373, 723, 131, 61))
        self.check.setObjectName("check")
        self.checklabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.checklabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 570, 71, 61))
        self.checklabel.setText("")
        self.checklabel.setObjectName("checklabel")
        self.scroll.raise_()
        self.warning.raise_()
        self.textabout.raise_()
        self.inputname.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.check.raise_()
        self.checklabel.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(descriptionperson)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(descriptionperson)

    def retranslateUi(self, descriptionperson):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        descriptionperson.setWindowTitle(_translate("descriptionperson", "Form"))
        self.warning.setText(_translate("descriptionperson", "ВНИМАНИЕ! РОЗЫСК!"))
        self.inputname.setText(_translate("descriptionperson", "Введите имя деятеля:"))
        self.check.setText(_translate("descriptionperson", "Проверить"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WordWrap работает !!!

Обратите внимание на свойства выделенные - `# +++`

Не совсем понял смысл флагов, которые вы установили. Поэтому они были отключены.

Начинайте смещаться от использования свойства setGeometry(const QRect &) и  move(QPoint(x, y)) в сторону макетов `QGridLayout, QBoxLayout, QHBoxLayout, QVBoxLayout, QStackedLayout, QFormLayout`

main.py

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtGui     import QPalette, QColor, QPixmap
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QListWidget
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from PyQt5 import QtCore
from newperson_ui import Ui_newperson
from descriptionperson_ui import Ui_descriptionperson

defaultStyle = 'color: #F0FF0C; background-color: green; font-size: 20px'  # <========


class DescriptionPersonPreview(QtWidgets.QWidget):          
    def __init__(self, text):
        super().__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_descriptionperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)

        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")

#        self.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.FramelessWindowHint)
#        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True) 
        self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_StyledBackground, True)

        self.ui.scroll.setPixmap(QPixmap())
        self.ui.scroll.setPixmap(QPixmap("images/head.jpg"))  

        self.textaboutpreview = text
        self.ui.textabout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.ui.textabout.setText(self.textaboutpreview)

        self.ui.textabout.setScaledContents(True)                        # +++
        self.ui.textabout.setWordWrap(True)                              # +++
        self.ui.textabout.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, # +++ 
                                        QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding) # +++

        self.setStyleSheet("background: blue; color: white;")            # +++
        self.ui.textabout.setStyleSheet(defaultStyle)                    # +++

# +++ ------------------------------------------
        layoutH1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH1.addWidget(self.ui.scroll)
        layoutH1.addWidget(self.ui.textabout)

        layoutH2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH2.addWidget(self.ui.inputname)
        layoutH2.addWidget(self.ui.lineEdit)

        layoutV = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(spacing=10)  
        layoutV.setContentsMargins(10, 50, 10, 30)   
        layoutV.addWidget(self.ui.warning)
        layoutV.addLayout(layoutH1)
        layoutV.addLayout(layoutH2)
        self.ui.check.setStyleSheet("""
            QPushButton:pressed{color: red} QPushButton{color: white}
            QPushButton:pressed{background-color: #FFF8DC} QPushButton{background-color: #E0DCBF}
            """)         
        layoutV.addWidget(self.ui.check)

        self.setLayout(layoutV)
# +++ -----------------------------------------        

class NewPerson(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.ui = Ui_newperson()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("Создание нового персонажа")
        self.name = ""
        self.text = ""
        self.FaceOfPerson = ""
        self.FacesOfPerson = ""
# События нажатия на кнопки
        self.ui.image.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImage)
        self.ui.makeperson.clicked.connect(self.MakeNewPerson)
        self.ui.preview.clicked.connect(self.Preview)
        self.ui.image_2.clicked.connect(self.ChoiceImages)
# Подключаем текстовые поля
        self.ui.name.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonName)
        #aboutpersontext
        #self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)
        self.ui.aboutpersontext.textChanged.connect(self.NewPersonAboutText)


# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ИМЯ"
    def NewPersonName(self, name):
        self.name = name

# ТЕКСТОВОЕ ПОЛЕ "НОВОЕ ОПИСАНИЕ"
    def NewPersonAboutText(self):
        self.text = self.ui.aboutpersontext.toPlainText()
#        print("def NewPersonAboutText(self):", self.text)


# ФУНКЦИЯ Загрузки изображения
    def ChoiceImage(self):
        self.FaceOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Выберите картинку с лицом исторической личности", None, "Image (*.png *.jpg)")[0]

        print(self.FaceOfPerson)

# ФУНКЦИЯ Загрузки изображения фантомов
    def ChoiceImages(self):
        self.FacesOfPerson = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self, "Выберите картинку с лицами фантомов", None, "*.png *.jpg")
        print(self.FacesOfPerson[0][0]) #[1])

# ФУНКЦИЯ Открытия окна Предварительного просмотра
    def Preview(self):
        self.preview = DescriptionPersonPreview(self.text) 
        self.preview.show()

###        
    def MakeNewPerson(self):
        print("def MakeNewPerson(self):")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    gui = NewPerson()
    gui.show()
    app.exec_()
```

descriptionperson_ui.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_descriptionperson(object):
    def setupUi(self, descriptionperson):
        descriptionperson.setObjectName("descriptionperson")
        descriptionperson.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        descriptionperson.resize(800, 500)                        # 800, 850

        self.warning = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.warning.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(300, 61, 201, 31))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setFamily("Moscow Sans Regular")
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.warning.setFont(font)
        self.warning.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.warning.setObjectName("warning")

        self.scroll = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.scroll.setEnabled(True)
#        self.scroll.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 850))
        self.scroll.setText("")
        self.scroll.setObjectName("scroll")

        self.textabout = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
#        self.textabout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 110, 581, 541))
        self.textabout.setText("")
#        self.textabout.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeading|QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft|QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        self.textabout.setObjectName("textabout")

        self.inputname = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.inputname.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(173, 653, 181, 61))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(12)
        self.inputname.setFont(font)
        self.inputname.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.inputname.setObjectName("inputname")

        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(descriptionperson)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(353, 674, 171, 20))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.check = QtWidgets.QPushButton(descriptionperson)
        self.check.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(373, 723, 131, 61))  
        self.check.setObjectName("check")
        self.checklabel = QtWidgets.QLabel(descriptionperson)
        self.checklabel.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 570, 71, 61))
        self.checklabel.setText("")
        self.checklabel.setObjectName("checklabel")
        self.scroll.raise_()
        self.warning.raise_()
        self.textabout.raise_()
        self.inputname.raise_()
        self.lineEdit.raise_()
        self.check.raise_()
        self.checklabel.raise_()

        self.retranslateUi(descriptionperson)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(descriptionperson)

    def retranslateUi(self, descriptionperson):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        descriptionperson.setWindowTitle(_translate("descriptionperson", "Form"))
        self.warning.setText(_translate("descriptionperson", "ВНИМАНИЕ! ВНИМАНИЕ!"))
        self.inputname.setText(_translate("descriptionperson", "Введите имя деятеля:"))
        self.check.setText(_translate("descriptionperson", "Проверить"))
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `self.setAttribute(QtCore.Qt.WA_TranslucentBackground, True)` Мне нужно убрать задний фон.Чтобы мой текст выглядел вот так. Как видите у меня не переносится текст https://imgur.com/a/KjBoxP0

Comment: wordWrap : bool свойство содержит политику текстового обмена словами `при разрыве слов`, `а не слова`.  На вашей картинке я вижу `ОДНО слово` и как вы хотите его перенести? В общем для переноса слов нужен нормальный текст, состоящий из слов.

Comment: Спасибо. Что то я тупанул