# Как заставить текст в QLabel переноситься на новую строку, если ему не хватает места?

Tags: python, ооп, pyqt, qlabel

Мой код содержит достаточно много контейнеров. Я попытаюсь рассказать о них. Хотел упростить конструкцию, но, как показывает практика, лучше объяснить ситуацию подробнее и оставить в примере больше деталей:

- Главный контейнер - `main_box`. *Включает:*
- `color_box` - цветной контейнер;
- `scroll_box` - контейнер, связанный с областью прокрутки. *Включает:*

  - Три цветных контейнера `little_box`;
  - `box_h` - горизонтальный контейнер. *Включает:*

    - `box_v1` - вертикальный контейнер;
    - `box_v2` - вертикальный контейнер.

В `box_v1` находится `picture` - изображение с закругленными краями. 
Его получаю с помощью класса `RoundArt`.

В `box_v2` находятся две надписи - `label1` и `label2`.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

`label2` нужна, чтобы сохранить форму макета, никак задействовать ее не нужно.

---

А вот `label1` хотелось бы полностью переделать. Мне нужно, чтобы текст внутри `label1` переходил на новую строку, если окно приложения становится слишком маленьким. Есть несколько условий:

1. Если это возможно, текст располагается на одной строке.
2. Если места становится слишком мало, текст частично переползает на
   вторую строку, пока ему это необходимо.
3. Текст может располагаться `максимум на двух строках`. На третью
   переходить он **не должен**.
4. Если двух строк становится мало, приложение должно обрезать текст
   тремя точками:

Было - looooong text >>> Стало - looo...

**^^^** Текст стал непозволительно длинным, и приложение обрезало его

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Честно говоря, сейчас я вообще не представляю, как такое можно организовать.

Для меня это очень сложно, но я не знаю, насколько это трудоемкая задача на самом деле. 
Может быть, это делается вручную на сотни строк кода, а может быть, для этого существует специальный виджет? 
Из-за этого я даже не знаю, насколько корректный задал вопрос. 
Возможно, я сейчас слишком много хочу.

---

Есть две причины, которые объясняют, почему мне это нужно.

Первая причина довольно очевидная - я хочу, чтобы текст было лучше видно.

Вторая причина заключается в том, что вместе с текстом становится не видно надписи в контейнерах `little_box`. Эти надписи я специально прижимаю к правому боку. Я думаю, что, когда для надписи `label1` становится слишком мало места, перестает масштабироваться весь контейнер `scroll_box`, хотя контейнеры `little_box` еще могут уменьшаться.

Я немного потерялся и мог забыть что-нибудь очень важное. 
Пожалуйста, дайте знать, если что-то не объяснил или объяснил плохо.
Пожалуйста, помогите мне.

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundArt(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundArt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10 
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)
        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(900, 600)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setWidget(container)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        main_box.addWidget(scrollArea, 0, 0)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setFixedHeight(220)
        scroll_box.addWidget(container)
        box_h = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)

        picture = RoundArt('Fc414959288ga866.png', 200)
        box_v1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        box_v1.addWidget(picture)
        box_h.addLayout(box_v1)
        box_h.addSpacing(10)

        box_v2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        box_v2.addSpacing(10)

        label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel('very looooooooooooooong label')
        label1.setStyleSheet(qss_lb)
        label1.setFixedHeight(30)
        box_v2.addWidget(label1)
        box_v2.addSpacing(20)

        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label')
        label2.setStyleSheet(qss_lb)
        label2.setFixedHeight(30)
        box_v2.addWidget(label2)
        box_v2.addSpacing(10)

        box_h.addLayout(box_v2)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #3A4256;')
        container.setFixedWidth(200)
        main_box.addWidget(container, 0, 1)
        color_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('color box')
        label.setStyleSheet(qss_lb)
        color_box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        for i in range(0, 3):
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            container.setStyleSheet('background: #3A4256;')
            container.setFixedHeight(50)
            little_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel('label')
            little_box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
            scroll_box.addWidget(container)


qss_lb = '''QLabel {
                font: bold 25px;
            }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: я пока что не вникал в ваш вопрос, посмотрите это то что вам надо https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qlabel.html#wordWrap-prop ?

Comment: если да, то я публиковал несколько постов с этим, например https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/904131/wordwrap-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82/904184#904184

Comment: К сожалению, это работает абсолютно не так, как я хотел. Когда не хватает места, слова просто пропадают, а не обрезаются. Так-же почему-то `scroll_box` начинает очень некорректно масштабироваться. Если это нужно, я могу объянить все, обновив вопрос

Comment: Для картинки оставьте QLabel, а для текста используйте QTextEdit с переводом строки

Comment: Добавьте `label1.setWordWrap(True)` и удалите `label1.setFixedHeight(30)`, оно ? Пояснение к вопросу я  еще не читал.

Comment: @AlexanderChernin Спасибо,надо посмотреть

Comment: @S.Nick К сожалению, не совсем. Количество строк не контролируется. А я хотел оставить максимум две строки

Comment: а с `label1.setFixedHeight(60)`

Comment: Теперь с количеством строк все в порядке. Но я описывал то, что хотел отбрезать слова с помощью трех точек, если им не хватает места

Comment: как может меняться длина `label1`, сколько слов минимум и сколько слов максимум ? и как вы ее будете формировать, откуда она берется ?

Comment: @S.Nick, я не могу сказать про максимум, т.к. текст излекается из тегов MP3-файла, а в тегах может находится строка любой длины и любым количеством слов. Минимум - 1 символ

Comment: В любом случае, я могу при сохранении в БД задать максимальное количество слов

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем, вам надо изучить:

`QFontMetricsF Class` -> https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtGui

class RoundArt(QtWidgets.QLabel):
    clicked = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, picture, x, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RoundArt, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.setFixedSize(x, x)
        self.x = x
        self.radius = 10 
        self.setPicture(picture)

    def setPicture(self, picture):
        target = QtGui.QPixmap(self.size())
        target.fill(QtCore.Qt.transparent)
        p = QtGui.QPixmap(picture).scaled(
            self.x, self.x, QtCore.Qt.KeepAspectRatioByExpanding,
            QtCore.Qt.SmoothTransformation
        )
        painter = QtGui.QPainter(target)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.HighQualityAntialiasing, True)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.SmoothPixmapTransform, True)
        path = QtGui.QPainterPath()
        path.addRoundedRect(0, 0, self.width(), self.height(), self.radius, self.radius)
        painter.setClipPath(path)
        painter.drawPixmap(0, 0, p)
        self.setPixmap(target)
        painter.end()
        target = None

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        self.clicked.emit()


class MyWindow(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.resize(900, 600)

        main_box = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self)

        scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea()
        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        scrollArea.setMinimumWidth(390)                                               # +++
        scrollArea.setMinimumHeight(235)                                              # +++

        scrollArea.setWidget(container)
        scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        scrollArea.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(QtCore.Qt.ScrollBarAlwaysOff)
        scroll_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)
        main_box.addWidget(scrollArea, 0, 0)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setFixedHeight(220)
        scroll_box.addWidget(container)
        box_h = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)

        picture = RoundArt('head3.png', 200)
        box_v1 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        box_v1.addWidget(picture)
        box_h.addLayout(box_v1)
        box_h.addSpacing(10)

        box_v2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        box_v2.addSpacing(10)


# +++ vvv
        self.text = 'я не могу сказать про максимум, т.к. текст излекается из тегов MP3-файла, '\
                    'а в тегах может находится строка любой длины.'

        self.label1 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.text)                                # +++ text
        self.label1.setWordWrap(True)                                            # +++    
#        self.label1.setStyleSheet(qss_lb)
        self.label1.resize(418, 55)                                              # +++
        self.label1.setFixedHeight(55)                                           # 30 -> 55
        self.label1.setMinimumWidth(130)                                         # +++
        self.label1.setFont(QtGui.QFont("Consolas", 20, QtGui.QFont.Bold))       # +++
# +++ ^^^        
        box_v2.addWidget(self.label1)
        box_v2.addSpacing(20)

        label2 = QtWidgets.QLabel('label')
        label2.setStyleSheet(qss_lb)
        label2.setFixedHeight(30)
        box_v2.addWidget(label2)
        box_v2.addSpacing(10)

        box_h.addLayout(box_v2)

        container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        container.setStyleSheet('background: #3A4256;')
        container.setFixedWidth(200)
        main_box.addWidget(container, 0, 1)
        color_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(container)

        label = QtWidgets.QLabel('color box')
        label.setStyleSheet(qss_lb)
        color_box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)

        for i in range(0, 3):
            container = QtWidgets.QWidget()
            container.setStyleSheet('background: #3A4256;')
            container.setFixedHeight(50)
            little_box = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(container)
            label = QtWidgets.QLabel('label')
            little_box.addWidget(label, alignment = QtCore.Qt.AlignRight)
            scroll_box.addWidget(container)

# ++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    def resizeEvent(self, event):
        super(MyWindow, self).resizeEvent(event)
        w = self.label1.size().width()

        # https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfontmetricsf.html#averageCharWidth
        # Возвращает среднюю ширину глифов в шрифте.
        fw = self.label1.fontMetrics().averageCharWidth() 

        x = w * 2 // fw - 12                        # 12 - какое-то корректирующее число

        self.label1.setText(self.text[:x] + ' ...')

# ++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


qss_lb = '''QLabel {
                font: bold 23px;
            }'''

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = MyWindow()
    window.setWindowTitle(' ')
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

**Update**

> Есть одна деталь - три точки ... никуда не уходят, если тексту хватает места. Я забыл уточнить это в вопросе. Буду очень рад узнать, как это поправить, если вы знаете решение, и вам не трудно.

Замените:

```
self.label1.setText(self.text[:x] + ' ...')
```

на что-то такое:

```
    if (w * 2 // fw) > (len(self.text) ):       
        self.label1.setText(self.text)
    else:
        self.label1.setText(self.text[:x] + ' ...')
```

Comment: Большое спасибо. Прошу прощения, что так поздно, был очень занят. Есть одна деталь - три точки `...` никуда не уходят, если тексту хватает места. Я забыл уточнить это в вопросе. Буду очень рад узнать, как это поправить, если вы знаете решение, и вам не трудно. Сейчас не представляю никакого возможного способа :( Я могу задать новый вопрос, если это нужно

Comment: @MAXIM045  я добавил обновление

Comment: Большое спасибо! Теперь мне необходимо разобрать код. Примерно в 10-30 процентах случаев происходят баги и три точки просто пропадают. Я думаю, слова переходят на третью строчку, которая скрыта. Я пропаду примерно на дня два - буду пытаться решить проблему, но не уверен, что смогу :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 вам надо изучить раздел, о котором я писал. Поиграться с тем, что обозначено как `какое-то корректирующее число`.и возможно добавить `какое-то корректирующее число` в условие, опубликованное в обновлении.

Comment: Добрый день. Прошу прощения, что пропал. Сейчас у меня не очень много свободного времени, из-за чего я ненадолго отложу изучение модуля. Пишу вам, просто потому, что хотел сказать спасибо за помощь в течение нескольких месяцев. Вы знаете, что я пытался работать над школьным проектом. Недавно я сдал эту работу на отлично. Без вашей помощи, я бы опустил руки и не пришел ни к чему. Спасибо :)

Comment: @MAXIM045 пожалуйста. Будут вопросы обращайтесь, всегда поможем.